# Approximating $\sin 100$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

If Taylor polynomial for $\sin(x)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} $. What do I have to do to find what degree of Taylor polynomial I have to use so the error is not greater than $10^{-4}$ in approximation of $\sin(100)$?

Comment: It's  true only around 0.

Comment: Well, since the series alternates, and decreases for sufficiently large terms, you could just use Sterling's approximation.  But surely it is more efficient to use periodicity...$32\pi\approx 100.5309649$ helps.

Comment: Are you looking for $x$ so $\sin x=100$ (title) or $\sin x$ when $x=100$ (body)?

Comment: Sorry, wrong title. I edited it.

Comment: Why using this series in practice is a really bad idea: the largest term in the alternating series is about $\approx 100^{100}/100! \approx 10^{42}$. Thus if you are to use the alternating series to compute it you would need to add about $300$ numbers that would be up to $47$ digits long (you also need $5$ decimal digits to get the desired precision). This would not even work on a computer unless you used arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: It's a problem I got to solve with the quoted series. That's why I'm confused

Comment: As a theoretical exercise its a perfectly fine problem (you just need to find a $n$ such that the $n$th term is less than $10^{-4}$ and as said above this can be done using Stirlings approximation). My comment was as to do this calculation in practice.

Comment: This is my approach, by the remainder theorem we have that $|R_{n}(100) \leq | \frac {sin^{(n)}(100)}{(n+1)!}| \leq \frac {1}{(n+1)!}$

For $n=4$ it won't work, but for n=7 we get that $\frac{1}{8!} \leq 0.0001$ . Can you clarify if this is correct or not?

Comment: Your remainder term is not correct.  It needs a factor $x^n$ in it, which is huge and why Winther gets that you need so many terms

Comment: Is the 100 in degrees or radians? Without decorations on the number we assume the latter, but as an exercise the degree variant would make a little more sense.

Comment: Without using the value of $\pi$, you can use angle reduction using the double-angle trigonometric identities. Set $x=100/2^6=1.5625$, then compute $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ with an error less than $10^{-8}$ using the Taylor expansions, and then reconstruct the wanted quantities using $\sin(2^{k+1}x)=2\sin(2^kx)\cos(2^kx)$ and $\cos(2^{k+1}x)=\cos^2(2^kx)-\sin^2(2^kx)$ or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a(n eventually) converging alternating series, so the alternating series theorem applies.  Find the first term after it starts decreasing that is less than $10^{-4}$ in magnitude and you are done.

Probably you are expected to look up the error term for the Taylor series.  Note that all the derivatives of $\sin x$ are less than $1$ in magnitude, so you can ignore that.

As the comments point out, you will get there with many fewer terms if you are allowed to center the Taylor series at $32\pi$ instead of $0$.

Comment: If it's not mentioned where the Taylor series is centered at, what do I use as a default for this particular problem?

Comment: The series you quote is centered at $0$.  The closer you can center the series to the point of interest the better because all those $x^i$ terms in your series become $(x-c)^i$ where $c$ is the point you center at.  As you can easily calculate trig functions of $32\pi$ that is a good place.